# Why is std::set_intersection not working?

Tags: c++, stl, set-intersection

I have the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

int main() {
// your code goes here
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    string a;
    string b;
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    vector<char> v1(a.begin(),a.end());
    vector<char> v2(b.begin(),b.end());

    sort(v1.begin(),v1.end());
    sort(v2.begin(),v2.end());
    vector<char> c;
    auto ls = set_intersection(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end(),c.begin());
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    cout<<ls-c.begin()<<endl;
    cout<<c.size()<<endl;

}
return 0;
}
```

Nothing is printed after the set_intersection line, not even "hello" which has no relation to the intersection line, why??

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: `typedef long long ll;` - *Why*? Are you trying to intentionally obfuscate your code for future readers?

Comment: Also recommend reading [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: This is a competitive programming code, and I have read in many articles to use this to decrease time in coding. Is it ok to do so?

Comment: @VamsiMohan Well, nothing stops you from doing it, and it could save a few seconds of typing. But keep in mind that in actual real-world programming, those are considered bad practices. If you're doing competitive programming to learn regular programming, I'd avoid those.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @VamsiMohan -- What good will those shortcuts do you if you don't know the basics of how to handle the STL algorithms, such as `std::set_intersection`?  Second, if a programmer has a problem with a certain aspect of C++, they would write a very small `main` program using the facility they are having an issue with, and work on the small `main` program to figure out how to use that aspect of C++.  Writing `while t--` loops and all of that doesn't help matters.  I would expect two vectors filled in with data, and testing `set_intersection` calls -- nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because `c` is *empty*. This means that `c.begin()` be equal to `c.end()`, and dereferencing an end iterator leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to insert the elements in the vector, for example by using [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
auto ls = set_intersection(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end(),back_inserter(c));
```

---

There's one problem with this though: The iterator that `set_intersection` will return is the end of the `back_inserter` iterator you passed to the `set_intersection` function. That iterator is not related to `c.begin()` which means you can't really do `ls - c.begin()`.

Unfortunately there's really no way to get the distance between the initial `back_inserter(c)` iterator and `ls`.

Comment: cant we call c.size() to get it's length? Forgive me if I am wrong, I am pretty new to C++

Comment: @VamsiMohan Of course, you can. You can't use the iterator distance but `c.size()` will work fine.